# Reconstruct 3D object with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera, calibration

I am following the OpenCV camera calibration tutorial  https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html to run camera calibration

```py
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
```

What I want to do next is to reconstruction the 3D location of some feature points. The features points are defined in the image space. Here is what I am planning to do:

1. Found the new camera matrix:

```py
h,  w = my image dimension
newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))
```

2. Undistort the feature point location:

```py
new_points= cv2.undistortPoints(my_feature_points, mtx, dist, P=newcameramtx)
```

3. Reconstruct the 3D coordinate of the feature points for a given Z. I have two problems here. First, I do not know how to reconstruct the 3D coordinate. 2. When I do it, should I use the original camera matrix "mtx" or the new camera matrix "newcameramtx". And how about "roi"? where should I apply it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: your question is not properly formated, please present in a readable way

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this version](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) of the docs, which I find easier to read.  The key equation is this one:

[image: camera equation]

Once you have undistorted your image this equation applies.  The matrix with *fx*, *fy*, *cx*, and *cy* is your camera matrix, often called *M*.

This equation tells you how to go from 2D pixel locations, on the left (*x*, *y*), to 3D locations in the world (on the right, [*X*, *Y*, *Z*].

> First, I do not know how to reconstruct the 3D coordinate

To do that, we can apply the equation.  Given a pixel location and a range (plug in as *w*), we have:

[image: inv M]

which we can do in code like so:

```
pixels = [x, y, range]
XYZ = np.mult( np.linalg.inv(mtx), pixels)
```

I'm not sure that you want to be calling [getOptimalNewCameraMatrix](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#getoptimalnewcameramatrix), because that is cropping out pixels that may not be valid.  I'd skip that for the moment until you have a better understanding of the system.  The ROI is telling you where the *undistorted* image won't have any blank pixels.

I really recommend the book Learning OpenCV (or the new version 3 one); it helped me a huge amount.  It took me from getting really frustrated reading the docs (which assume a lot of prior knowledge) to actually understanding what was going on.

Comment: Thank you for your post. 1) I need to call getOptimalNewCameraMatrix because the newcameramtx is need to undistort my feature points. 2) How can I get the "range"?

Comment: Also, I think pixels=[x*Z, y*Z, Z]

Comment: The range is your Z in "reconstruct the 3D coordinate of the feature points for a given Z"  The 2D image cannot tell you the range of any given point -- you'd need a stereo rig or something similar for that.  In pixels = [x, y, range], those x and y values are integer coordinates on your image.

Comment: As my mentioned, if I use the formula you proposed, the results was not correct. If I set pixels=[xZ, yZ, Z] , however, the results was correct

Comment: See a working example here https://github.com/rodolfoap/screen2world-k